# Not able to read the database when connected to android mobile

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-emulator

I have a sqlite database developed in iphone application, i have copied the database in to emulator ( copied in to package databases folder).
I am able to read and everything is working fine using emulator, but when i connected to android mobile i am not able to read the database, and exceptions are coming that no such table etc..
How to solve it?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us what you are doing? What _exact_ stacktraces are you getting?

Comment: you've to create the database by code.

Comment: @cdeszaq: i am getting no such table exception

Comment: @a fair player: is there any other way of doing it, because it will take much time if i create and insert the data through code, but why it working using emulator

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 1):

How are you copying the Sqlite database on to the mobile device? Are you bundling it with the APK?

If you are just attempting to upload it via the ADB, you will not be able to as physical devices are locked down for security reasons to stop people implanting/stealing data on real devices.

I suspect the upload has simply not worked on the physical device which is why you are seeing "missing table" type errors.

Comment: i have just connected the mobile to pc and running the application